# Calculate Pi in C up to a few million digits

Tags: c, pi

I am actually very new to C, but for a project, I'd like to be able to calculate the value of Pi from 1 million to at least 32 million decimal places.
Basically, like what SuperPi/HyperPi does for benchmarking a CPU.

But obviously, the standard C library is incapable of this.

What library can I use, and what algorithm do I use for this task?

And precision too, anyone can cook up a rand() bloat and call it the "Ultimate value of Pi".

My compiler is GCC, so if possible, I'd like the library to be able to compile on it(I have the BigNum library).

Comment: Do you want to calculate it yourself, or use a ready made solution (like eg `printf("%s\n", expandpi(1000000));`)?

Comment: You might like the [wikipedia article about PI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Computation_in_the_computer_age), if you haven't read it yet :)

Comment: The standard C library is capable of most anything, it'll just take a lot more work.

Comment: If it really was, there would be no use of the BigNum library, now would it. Anyway, as I said before, I am still new to C, so I'd like to not have more work :).

Comment: **Hint:** This is not an easy task... (also note who is posting this comment)

Comment: If you want to calculate it by yourself, the standard C library is indeed sufficient. If you don't need to print it out, just calculate it you can do it even without the standard C library, just using pure C.

Comment: I've done this for a school project some time ago. I implemented my own bignum library (with FFT multiplication) with the help of Knuth and the last chapter of Numerical Recipes. I'd suggest http://www.mpfr.org/ if you don't want to do that.

Comment: I would very much like to print it, yes, but not on the screen, but to a file.

Comment: @AlexandreC. Now that's pretty hard core. :) I thought I was one of the only ones...

Comment: @Mystical: it is not very hard. Everything fits under 1000 lines of code if you keep the code straightforward. The point in using a library is performance.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I meant without the library. Implementing your own FFT from scratch and integrating into the large multiplication.

Comment: @Mystical: 1000 lines without any library. A straightforward Cooley-Tukey takes 50ish lines. At the time I did this, the point was to understand what was a DFT...

Comment: `FILE *fp = fopen("pi_1000000.txt", "r"); while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v used the quadratic algorithm from [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm) with success. I'd suggest [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) for the library part.

Comment: +1, I would definitely recommend the AGM algorithms over any of the series algorithms. Especially since the series algorithms are only efficient when combined with some other obscure method.

Comment: @Mysticial: and the theory is quite understandable (and pretty) with entry level calculus.

Answer (score 2):

As for the algorithm, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm. For a library to deal with bignums, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries. Have fun.